# URL rewriting with htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL that looks like:

```
domain.com/home/login.php?ref=501201
```

I want to re-write it as

```
domain.com/ref/501201
```

Please tell me the .htaccess syntax

```
RewriteRule ^ref/([0-9]+)$ /home/login.php?id=$1
```

because this doesn't work

Comment: And "this doesn't work" means what _exactly? Do you get an error? Do you see anything in your http servers error log files? Does a wrong rewriting occur? Does nothing happen at all? Does the universe implode?

Comment: If you really want to use dynamic configuration files (you should try not to...) then you need to enable those. Take a look at the `AllowOverride` directive the apache http server offers.

Comment: And you should add some more information to the question: where is that file located and please add the _full_ content of that file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This One is try it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?ref/([0-9]+)$ /home/login.php?id=$1
```

It's not tested. i hope is working

Comment: thanks , it's working but , there is one issue http://prntscr.com/frh4jd
it doesn't load the stylesheet